# solcx.exceptions.SolcError: Unknown key "*"

Tags: python, solidity-0.8.x, py-solc-x

I'm learning how to deploy a smart contract using a Python script and I keep getting the following error:

```
> py deploy.py

INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\Code\tutorials\blockchain\web3\deploy.py", line 10, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 391, in compile_standard
    raise SolcError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcError: Unknown key "*"
> command: `C:\Users\Lucas\.solcx\solc-v0.8.0\solc.exe --standard-json`
> return code: `0`
> stdout:
{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"Unknown key \"*\"","message":"Unknown key \"*\"","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}

> stderr:
```

This is the script for deploy.py:

```
import solcx
from solcx import compile_standard
solcx.install_solc('0.8.0')

# open & read SimpleStorage.sol
with open('./SimpleStorage.sol', 'r') as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

# compile solidity
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        'language': 'Solidity',
        'sources': {'SimpleStorage.sol': {'content': simple_storage_file}},
        'settings': {'*': {'*': ['abi', 'metadata', 'evm.bytecode', 'evm.sourceMap']}},
    },
    solc_version = '0.8.0'
)

print(compiled_sol)
```

I should probably mention that I'm following along a tutorial from freeCodeCamp on YouTube.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What if you omit `solcx.install_solc('0.8.0')`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your compile_standard call:

```
# compile solidity
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.8.0",
)
```

Refer to the course reference code here: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/web3_py_simple_storage/blob/main/deploy.py

Comment: Btw, I found this question by looking for a fix for the "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)." warning that's caused by the solcx import. If you know how to fix that please let me know.

Comment: I discovered that the INFO warning is caused by a call to 'where.exe solc' in the _get_which_solc function in the install.py of the solcx package. The code works despite that warning because it ends up using the solc that gets installed by the call to install_solc.